# Linux default file permission

Tags: linux, permissions

Is there someway to set the default file permission in Linux? That is, the file permission for a newly created file (regardless of the context for which it was created
). I know about putting umask in the shell startup but that only works for shell sessions. When I transfer files to a Linux box using **pscp**, the file is always created with permissions of 664 (rw-rw-r--). The has occurred across every flavor of Linux that I've used. This is especially annoying when I pscp a file to shared Linux machine (like my ISP). Until I can shell in and chmod the permission, the file is basically sitting there with read access for everyone, which is not exactly secure.

Comment: I'm not going to close this but I will say that I'm not sure this is programming related..

Comment: I'll say that the first answer posted is a programming related answer.  If you toss out script files executed by bash, zsh, and tcsh, then you have to toss out script files executed by cmd.exe, IIS, PowerShell, VBA, etc.

Comment: @SCdF: why is this not related to programming?  It seems within bounds to me.

Comment: It didn't work. I have umask 077 in various (.bash_profile, .tcshrc, .cshrc) startup files but it still defaults to 664. The problem is that I don't know what startup file the pscp server is using.

Comment: What shell are you using? Bash? What do you get when you run:

"ssh you@yourhost umask"

(or Putty's equivalent of "ssh")

Comment: (You should get "077" - otherwise, what shell are you using? Maybe I can help figure out the startup file you need to use.)

Answer (score 11):

Put the umask in the non-interactive shell startup (`.bash_profile`, `.zshenv`, `.tcshrc` depending on your shell). Then it'll run for non-login sessions.

Comment: How do I know what shell the pscp server is going to use?

Comment: When you log on (with putty), what shell does it start up?

Or, if you're logged on, "grep yourname /etc/passwd" and see what the last entry on that line is ("/bin/bash", for example.)

Comment: this didn't work for me. I put it in my .bash_profile and still have the same problem

Comment: @eviljack: can you tell me what shell you're using (grep yourname /etc/passwd)? Can you tell whether anything from .bash_profile runs when pscp connects? (Maybe put an "echo" in the file, and try plink, it might help diagnose the problem.)

Answer (score 5):

If you want to affect the whole system, you can also put it in /etc/profile

Comment: Is there a way to make it folder tree specific?  I want all of the files in say /var/www/html/sitename/ to have the same permissions regardless of who creates, edits, or moves files there.  Other than having a cron job that regularly chmod/chown's the directory recursively on a regular interval of course.

Comment: at least on ubuntu `/etc/login.defs` is used for a while now.